# Extract key sentences from a text

Tags: algorithm, text-processing, text-parsing, stemming

do you know about an effective method for extracting key sentences from a text with their frequency parameters, etc and that can also do "stemming" (search also for similar sentences) ?

I wonder also if there is some software implementation

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a list of [Peter Turney's papers about extracting keyphrases from text](http://www.apperceptual.com/ml_text_keys.html). Here's a list of [Text Summarization Resources](http://www.summarization.com/).[Stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) and [Text Similarity](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=337832) are different, large and evolving research areas. You have to give us a much more focused question in order to get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good natural language processing (NLP) toolkits which will do sentence identification and extraction.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing_toolkits for a list.

Your requirement for "similar sentences" needs clarification. Maybe you are looking for a treebank (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treebank) where sentences are parsed and compared.